# highcharts xAxis pointStart issue

Tags: javascript, highcharts

http://jsfiddle.net/whrTH/1/
the only different

```
 chart.series[0].update({
            pointStart: beginDate,
            pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000 * 7,
            data: someData
        }, false);

 chart.series[0].update({
            pointStart: beginDate,
            pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000 * 1,
            data: someData
        }, false);
```

when i click the day button, the code work well,  when i click the week button, it works also, However  the style of label show on xAxis is not what i want, what i want is every point has its label show on xAxis, just like when i click the day button. any help

Answer (score 0):

Use tickPositioner, see: http://jsfiddle.net/whrTH/2/

```
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',  
        tickPositioner: function(min,max) {
            return this.series[0].xData;
        },
        labels: {
            formatter: function(){ 
                return Highcharts.dateFormat('%d %b', this.value);
            }
        }
    },
```